# Отправка ссылки на email

Tags: url, email

Привет.

**Ситуация:**
Есть веб-форма получения электронного адреса, на который отправится ссылка на скачивание файла.

```
<form action="downloads.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="sender_email" placeholder="Ваш электронный адрес...">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Получить ссылку!">
</form>
```

**Проблема**

Я написал код для файла downloads.php:

```
//если пользователь нажал кнопку отправить
if (isset($_POST['send'])){

//получаем email
$email = $_POST['sender_email'];

//создаем письмо для отправки
$to = 'my@mail.ru';
$subject = 'Зарос загрузки файла с сайта';
$message.= 'Email:'.$email.'\n';

if (mail($to, $subject, $message)) echo 'Ссылка на загрузку файла отправлена на указанный Вами электронный адрес';
else echo 'Ссылка не отправлена';
}
```

Здесь не хватает обработчика отправки ссылки на электронный адрес пользователя, который ввёл свой email в веб-форму, и строки, куда нужно написать саму ссылку на скачивание файла, то есть это должно быть как сообщение.

Помогите дописать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, кому ты отправляешь письмо. Сейчас письмо отправляется на my@mail.ru с текстом, содержащим email посетителя. Что мешает написать еще одну строку mail, только вместо `$to` поставить `$email` и в `$message` написать ссылку на файл для скачивания?

Comment: Письмо с ссылкой должно отправляться пользователю, который ввел свой эл. адрес в веб-форму. На месте my@mail.ru мой эл.адрес. Мне должно приходить сообщение с эл. адресом пользователя, который ввел свой эл. адрес в веб-форму и нажал на кнопку send.